# System going slow after submit a lot of jobs to flink

Tags: apache-flink

We have a flink cluster that takes batch jobs hourly. Unfortunately, after running several days, we found that the system become slower and slower. The cpu cost become high even if there is no job running in the cluster. After restart the taskmanager, the system become fast again. Can someone give us hint or reference to explain way this happens?

Comment: can you provide some LOGS ?

Comment: Do you have one job that takes batches of inputs hourly or do you start a new job every hour? If the latter, do you actually end the job?